# How to force an "enter" on Python's input after x seconds?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, input, time

That's my code:

```
while True:
    prompt = "Enter code: "
    code = input(prompt)
    if code == "123":
        open_door()
```

The program automatically opens a door when the user types "123" on a USB keypad that does **not** have the "Enter" key.

Since my keypad does not have the "Enter" key, I want to force an "Enter" after 5 seconds. 5 seconds after the beginning of the loop, the program hits "Enter" no matter what has been typed. If by any chance `code` get to hold successfully "123" when "Enter" is hit, the door is open; otherwise, there'll be a second chance.

How can I do that?

Addt’l info: this program will run in a Raspberry Pi 3, but I am using Mac for the tests.

*Please note that "buying a keypad that has an "Enter" key" is not possible, because it's not actually a keypad; it's a RFID reader that works exactly like a keypad. I preferred to use "keypad" for understandability.*

Comment: Specify some end-character and try to use this [package](https://pypi.org/project/getch/) for reading by character.

Comment: Ignore my first comment, I misread. Is there not a library for this tech? I find it unusual that it relies on the standard `input()`

Comment: @roganjosh It does not rely on the standard `input()`. Actually it relies on nothing. It is a USB reader that when near an RFID card it types the card's code just like a keypad. It just "presses keys" but does not press "Enter" at the end. If I had Notepad open, it would type the card's code into the Notepad, if I had Calculator open, it would type the code into Calculator.

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me:

```
import pyautogui
import threading

def break_input():
    time.sleep(5)
    pyautogui.press('enter')

while True:
    threading.Thread(target=break_input).start()
    prompt = "Enter code: "
    code = input(prompt)
    if code == '123':
        open_door()
```

You will need the third-party library `pyautogui`.